# Reading checkbox name from text file

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to read a checkbox name from a txt file. I'm not sure if this is posible but i tried this:

```
Me.(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\Settings\language.txt")).Checked = 1
```

Sadly it didnt work, i get the error "identifier expected" and it underlines the dot after the Me.

Comment: That's a silly way to do something.  But it would be `Me.Controls(controlName).Checked = True`

Comment: Dont confuse an object reference with a control name

Comment: lars it didnt work

Comment: Well, use the debugger to see what the value you are getting from the file.  Use Path.Combine to properly create your file paths.  Your file has only a single control name in it?  Is the CheckBox in a container control like a panel?

Comment: i cant even start the program it just doesnt work

Comment: You want help, but you are giving us **nothing** to help you with.

Comment: I guess this will work https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=496043

Comment: @Thiplol You have to change the `controlName` value in Lars example for the result of your `ReadAllText()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem here is understanding what things are resolved at compile time vs what things are resolved at run time.

A checkbox name is an **identifier** that must resolve at compile time. You see a nice name like `CheckBox1` in your source code, but when the program actually runs all you really have is a **reference** consisting mainly of a number representing an offset into your program's memory address space. The `CheckBox1` name as a variable no longer exists; only the object reference remains.

On the other hand, `StartupPath` and the contents of the text file are only **strings**. They are not identifiers, and their values are not known until much later, when the program is already running.

The good news is, in the case of WinForms controls the variable name is preserved as data in the Control object, and you can search for it. You just need to use a method that will look at your Control objects, like this:

```
Dim language As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "\Settings\language.txt"))
Dim languageBox as CheckBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls(language), CheckBox)
```

Or maybe this:

```
Dim languageBox as CheckBox = Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().FirstOrDefault(Function(box) box.Name = language)
```

Or maybe your checkbox is nested within a GroupBox or Panel. In that case, you need to change `Me` for the name of the GroupBox, Panel, or other container control that directly holds the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

what is the name of checkbox in form ?...

```
        Dim _chkbxName$ = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\Settings\language.txt")
        For Each cnt As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf cnt Is CheckBox Then
                If cnt.Name = _chkbxName Then
                    CType(cnt, CheckBox).Checked = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
```